# Isotope.js dynamically changing sort data values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to dynamically change the sort data values on Isotope items, but Isotope seems to cache the initial order values and only use that on the `'reLayout'` call.

I have a page of items that, when clicked, will expand to 100% of the container width. Upon resize, all the Isotope items have to be re-ordered to specific positioning. I loop through each box and update the sort value.

The following example shows two Isotope objects, the top with animation which produces the proper sort order values, but wrong positioning, and the second with what *should* be the correct result.

The full example: http://jsfiddle.net/eB85m/4/

Is there anyway for Isotope to retrieve the new sort data or to update the sort data values of Isotope directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right about Isotope caching the initial order values – from Isotope's documentation [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html#sortby_option):

> The data cache is built on initialization so it can be quickly accessed when sorting.

Isotope offers the [`updateSortData`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#updatesortdata) method to … well, update the sorting data after initialization. [Here's a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eB85m/5/).

```
// Update sort data
// http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#updatesortdata
$('#iso').isotope( 'updateSortData', $('#iso').children() );
```

to your original example and commented the 'reLayout' – updating isotope's sort options already takes care of that (ref. Isotope's [sorting demo](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/sorting.html)).

> ### V2 Update:
>
> In **V2** you can use `$('#iso').isotope('updateSortData').isotope();`
>   
> <sup><sub><sup>(per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485843/isotope-js-dynamically-changing-sort-data-values#comment48052595_15673080) below)</sup></sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you. I love you with all my heart. -random person looking for this info.

Comment: In V2 you can use $('#iso').isotope('updateSortData').isotope();